# Defining and initializing a static const array of non-const function pointers in C++

Tags: c++

Can't get it.
Using g++ compiler.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef void (* FPTR) ();

class Test
{
    void f1()
    {
        cout << "Do nothing 1" << endl;
    }

    void f2()
    {
        cout << "Do nothing 2" << endl;
    }

    static FPTR const fa[];
};

FPTR const Test::fa[] = {f1, f2};
```

Error:

```
test.cpp:22: error: argument of type ‘void (Test::)()’ does not match ‘void (* const)()’
test.cpp:22: error: argument of type ‘void (Test::)()’ does not match ‘void (* const)()’
```

I just want to obtain constant array of function pointers, so

```
fa[0] = f2;
```

will cause an error like 'modifying read-only member Test::fa'

Comment: `f1` and `f2` are member functions, not functions.  This is something very different.  I can't remember the syntax off-hand, so I'll just point you to this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html.

Comment: Thank you, looks like its time to fill the gaps in my c++ education =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is right. The pointer type is `void (Test::*)()`. Try it:

```
typedef void (Test::*FPTR)();

FPTR const Test::fa[] = { &Test::f1, &Test::f2 };  // nicer to read!
```

`f1` and `f2` are not functions (i.e. free functions), but (non-static) *member* functions. Those are very different animals: You can call a function, but you cannot just call a member function. You can only call a member function *on an instance object*, and anything else doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understood the problem.. Will try your code example in the morning

Answer (score 2):

`f1` and `f2` are not function pointers but member-function pointers, so you cannot assign them to an array of function pointers. You could add them to an array of member-function pointers of `Test`.